# Properly converting a CMYK image to RGB with RMagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I have been using the below to do a color conversion

```
    if @image.colorspace == Magick::CMYKColorspace
      # @image.colorspace #=> CMYKColorspace=12
      @image.colorspace = Magick::RGBColorspace
      @image = @image.negate
    end
```

It works, approximately, but the color luminosity is off.  The fact that I need to negate the image leaves a very bad smell.

The documentation mentions using color_profiles, but beyond that I can not find much.

I am now trying

```
@image = @image.quantize(16777216, Magick::RGBColorspace)
```

And the colors are better, but still off.

Comment: I don't know about Ruby and Rmagick, but ImageMagick itself can handle colour profiles, at least in theory. (CMYK has always been a Pain with IM as long as I can remember). Are you having trouble applying a profile, or does using a profile not change anything? What colour profile does the incoming material have, if any?

Comment: The incoming files, in this case, do have a profile.  I will investigate some more.  I got lost with the color profiles (like where do I download them? the ICC site was not much help).  Thanks.

Comment: Running out of space here ... See below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks Pekka, you tipped me off to the answer (+1).

You must have ImageMagick compiled with the [Little Color Management System (LCMS)](http://www.littlecms.com/) installed.  This may already be the case if an installer  or package was used.  But I was compiling from source.  It was as simple as installing LCMS from source and rebuilding ImageMagick (`./configure; make; make install`).

In ImageMagick the below works well to reproduce accurate color:

`convert FILENAME -profile /PATH_TO_PROFILE/sRGB.icm OUT.jpg`

So in RMagick I use the below:

```
if @image.colorspace == Magick::CMYKColorspace
   # Adjust the path as necessary
   @image.color_profile ="/usr/local/share/ImageMagick-6.5.4/config/sRGB.icm"
end

@image.write("out.jpg") { self.quality = 85 }
```

Comment: Any idea where to find or how to install color profiles with ImageMagick 6.8.0? Installed it using Homebrew and can't find any *.icm files on my OS X. Thanks for your otherwise very helpful answer!

Comment: On Mac OS X you can do 'brew install imagemagick --with-little-cms' to get imagemagick compiled with lcms support. On all plattforms you can do: convert -list configure
The DELEGATES line should contain lcms if properly installed

Answer (score 4):

I've spent a long time trying to go from a CMYK EPS to a RGB PNG using RMagick and Rails.  Hopefully this will be of use to someone:

```
def convert_image_from_cmyk_to_rgb( image )
  #puts image.alpha?
  if image.colorspace == Magick::CMYKColorspace
    image.strip!
    image.add_profile("#{Rails.root}/lib/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc")
    image.colorspace == Magick::SRGBColorspace
    image.add_profile("#{Rails.root}/lib/sRGB.icc")
  end
  image
end
```

You can download the ICC files direct from Adobe at http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/iccprofiles/iccprofiles_win.html

The only thing I haven't been able to suss is how to maintain transparency.  The EPS I want to use has a transparent background which is being turned into white.  Unfortunately I can't do something like `image.transparent( "white" )` as I have white in the image that I want to keep as white.

If I uncomment the `puts image.alpha?` in the above code it returns `false`.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible with the current version of RMagick, as I'm beginning to wonder if importing CMYK EPSs with transparency isn't supported.

Thanks!

Comment: My advice would be to ask about the transparency problem in a new question.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Have now done so at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833496/rmagick-convert-cmyk-eps-to-rgb-png-maintaining-transparent-background

Comment: edit this one to take the question out so that what remains is just an answer to this question

Comment: ICC color profiles for Mac can be found here http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=4074&fileID=3792

Comment: That double equals should be a single - `image.colorspace = Magick::SRGBColorspace`

Answer (score 2):

> The incoming files, in this case, do
>   have a profile. I will investigate
>   some more. I got lost with the color
>   profiles (like where do I download
>   them? the ICC site was not much help)

You are not the only one confused; I was too. There are discussions on the ImageMagick site that might be worth siftirng through: [Here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10759&p=34154) As far as I understood back then, properly working with profiles is possible when the profile used can be identified (e.g. a monitor profile) or is embedded in the file (which can be done at least for TIFF and JPG in Photoshop, I think). Check e.g. this: [Here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/321/321382.html). Good luck.

Comment: Getting close, I think.  Looks like Image Magick needs to be compiled with `--with-lcms=yes` and the LCMS library installed.  When I have a moment I will give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

I found that The Who's command line solution worked beautifully, but the RMagick solution did not work for me.

To get it to work in RMagick, I instead I had to use the Magick::Image#add_format method, which, according to the docs, will allow you to specify an source and destination profile. It  looks like this:

```
if img.colorspace == Magick::CMYKColorspace
  img.add_profile(RGB_COLOR_PROFILE)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

RE: LCMS on Centos 5.5, be sure to download and build the latest LCMS from source (vs. yum install).  Otherwise, IM won't find LCMS at build and you'll be scratching your head, like me, wondering why LCMS isn't included in IM delegate libs.