# RGB image to CMYK and soften colors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rgb, cmyk

How to

- convert from RGB to CMYK
- soften/reduce color weight (avoid melt in printing press)

in ruby? It's for a rails app. Links are ok, code examples are awsome.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to do this on server side? I'd think that this is something you'd want a person with printing experience do manually to be able to proof the result. Also what kind of format are we talking?

Comment: This project is probably a lot larger than you think - doing it properly involves a lot of involved calculations and arbitrary design choices. Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_separation#Color_separation_process and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specifications_for_Web_Offset_Publications

Comment: images taken by a digital camera is always RGB. The print server/software I need to communicate with requires a CMYK image. We will of course manually test the results before actual production, but then we'll automate, @dain. I'm not going to implement it myself @Mark, there must be people that have already done this, I hope!

Comment: RMagick? http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Related (you just want to do the reverse of the accepted answer, I think): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853359/properly-converting-a-cmyk-image-to-rgb-with-rmagick

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have imagemagick compiled with LCMS (on a mac `brew install imagemagick --with-little-cms`). You probably need to reinstall the rmagick gem after reinstalling imagemagick.

Next, get [Adobe ICC color profiles](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=4074&fileID=3792) (again, these are for mac, but I'm sure you have no trouble locating versions for other platforms).

Then fire up your editor, and do something along these lines.

```
image = Image.read("my_image.jpg")[0]
image.colorspace = Magick::CMYKColorspace
image.add_profile("path_to/adobe_icc_profiles/CMYK/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc")
image.write("my_image_cmyk.jpg")
```

Comment: thanks, thomax. We ended up having a third party service (terrible) handle it. Upvote for the fact that you revive an old thread to potentially help others, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

I would say, use RMagick: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

Make sure to use version 2 and on, though, since it works with Ruby 1.9, too. Version 1 only works with 1.8.

As for an example however, I am not insanely experienced with ImageMagick. You can start here though:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php

Comment: somebody already suggested rmagick, in a comment. Do you have any know-how or examples on rgb to cmyk?