# Ruby / RMagick rotate and combine images

Tags: ruby, image, rotation, composite, rmagick

I'm trying to rotate an image before composing it ontop of another, using RMagick with ruby. I can compose the overlaid image but when I try to rotate the image parts of the background are removed, like so...

[image]

Im not sure which CompositeOperator I should be using, or if this is the wrong approach all together?

```
image = Magick::Image.read("img.jpg").first         
overlay = Magick::Image.read("./overlay.png").first
overlay.rotate!(9)
image.composite!(overlay, 100, 50, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
image.to_blob
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before rotating set your background to none:

```
overlay.background_color = "none"
```

Other possible methods to use after the rotation:

```
img.transparent_chroma(low, high, opacity=TransparentOpacity, invert=false)
img.transparent(color, opacity=TransparentOpacity)
```

so in your case:

```
overlay.transparent!("white")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the image transparency with the :opacity parameter

http://alternateidea.com/blog/articles/2005/9/19/custom-image-overlays-with-rmagick

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/119556

http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-ruby/63271-transparent-image-using-rmagick.html

[RMagick: Convert CMYK EPS to RGB PNG maintaining transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833496/rmagick-convert-cmyk-eps-to-rgb-png-maintaining-transparent-background)