# ruby - Dragonfly - Force CMYK to RGB conversion when doing thumbnails

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, imagemagick, dragonfly-gem, locomotivecms

I'm using a nice enough cms ([locomotive](http://locomotivecms.com)([github](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine))) to allow some non-tech savy users to upload pictures to the system. The program is able to resize and crop pictures to any given size.

Trouble is, Internet explorer doesn't know how to deal with CMYK-encoded images. The users of this app are not exactly tech-savy; asking them to transform their images from CMYK to RGB is not an option. I'd like to modify locomotive so that it does the change automatically. I've been trying this for some hours but had no luck so far.

This is what I have found:

- Locomotive uses [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) to perform the resizing.
- Concretely, it uses dragonfly's [imagemagick](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/tree/master/lib/dragonfly/image_magick) module.
- The file that defines how Dragonfly is used in locomotive can be found [here](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/blob/master/lib/locomotive/dragonfly.rb).
- There is also a dragonfly [initializer file](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/blob/master/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb).

I have also found that what (think) I need is adding a `-colorspace RGB` option to the parameter sent to Imagemagick by Dragonfly. It doesn't look like Dragonfly provides an easy option to do that.

I've tried several things, the last one consisting on monkeypatching [Dragonfly's Imagemagick Processor](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/lib/dragonfly/image_magick/processor.rb) so that the `-colorspace RGB` option is always used. I've added this in locomotive's `config/initializers/dragonfly.rb`:

```
# locomotive's config/initializers/dragonfly.rb

# ... Locomotive's default initialization

module Dragonfly
  module ImageMagick
    class Processor
      alias :old_convert :convert
      def convert(temp_object, args='', format=nil)
        args += ' -colorspace RGB' # force RGB in all thumbnails 
        old_convert(temp_object, args, format)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I was pretty sure that this should work, but unfortunately it doesn't. And I have run out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this with Dragonfly. I've given up.

Answer (score 1):

On the commandline, I sometimes need to add `-type truecolor` to make colorspace conversions work reliably:

```
convert cmyk.jpeg -colorspace rgb -type truecolor rgb.jpeg
```

Maybe you try to add it in your code as well?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I can't spend more time on this particular feature; I have coded my way around it, so I don't need it any more. I was having trouble getting params on the command line on my main question, so I think it would not work anyway, but I will not try your solution, I'm afraid. In any case, +1 for being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From the related list to the right, might this SO answer help?

[Properly converting a CMYK image to RGB with RMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853359/properly-converting-a-cmyk-image-to-rgb-with-rmagick)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That question doesn't use the native ImageMagick interface; instead it relies on RMagick. I can't change the whole Locomotive to use RMagick, I'm afraid.